# Как после выбора в select отобразить соответствующее содержимое?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

Как переписать скрипт, чтобы вкладки работели с тегом select? Т.е. при выборе нужного option отображало соответствующее содержимое.

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
$(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
    $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <select class="wrapper">
   <div class="tabs">
     <option class="tab">Вкладка 1</option>
     <option class="tab">Вкладка 2</option>
     <option class="tab">Вкладка 3</option>        
   </div>
   <div class="tab_content">
     <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
     <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
     <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
   </div>
 </select>

Comment: нельзя вставлять ничего в <select> кроме <option>

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
    <select class="tabs">
      <option class="tab">Вкладка 1</option>
      <option class="tab">Вкладка 2</option>
      <option class="tab">Вкладка 3</option>        
    </select>
    <div class="tab_content">
      <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
      <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
      <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: Немного зафейлил, вот так вот если поставить табы всёравно не работают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();

$(".tabs").change(function() {
  $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).val()).fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="tabs">
    <option value="0">Вкладка 1</option>
    <option value="1">Вкладка 2</option>
    <option value="2">Вкладка 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="tab_content">
    <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек)

Comment: Рад помочь))) Если ответ подошел, то отмечайте пожалуйста ответ и закрывайте вопрос))